# style css fieldset primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

```
   <p:fieldset legend="Simple FieldSet"  style=" font-size: 12px;       
   padding: 1em;float:left; ; margin-right:0.5em; padding-top:0.2em; text-align:left; 
  border:1px solid green; font-weight:bold;">
```

but I want to eliminate the background where it is written the text "Simple FieldSet" it collects as a button

Comment: You mean it looks like a button?

Comment: yes exactly it looks like a button

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using:

```
.ui-fieldset .ui-state-default {
    background: none;
}
```

Put it in a custom css file in your template.